# create table if not exists

Tags: mysql, sql

To prevent an error if I am creating a table with the same name of an existing table I use the keywords `IF NOT EXISTS`.

Now I have a question, the `IF` is the `IF` function or is it just another constructor?

Comment: In this context, IF is a keyword; so are NOT and EXISTS.  They're not related to the IF function, the NOT logical function, or the EXISTS qualifier for sub-queries (except that they happen to be spelled the same).

Comment: Not sure why the downvote - seems a valid question. @JonathanLeffler That looks like an answer - why not post it as one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, IF is a keyword, and so are NOT and EXISTS. They're not related to the IF function, the NOT logical operator, or the EXISTS qualifier for sub-queries (except that they happen to be spelled the same).  They're just a series of three keywords (which could be thought of as a single compound keyword 'IF NOT EXISTS') which modify the behaviour of the CREATE TABLE statement.